# Python To PostgreSQL - ST_GeometryFromText and NaN

Tags: arcpy, postgresql, well-known-text

I am trying to import a shapefile into Postgre using python and psycopg2. I have run into a few issues.

I am using ST_GeometryFromText() of a WKT string.

First, the shape@WKT returns MULTIPOLYGON ZM at the beginning of the string. I believe that it is only supposed to be MULTIPOLYGON correct?

I fixed this by doing a replace on the string but this does not seem like what should be done. What do I do to make this correct?

Second, the shape@WKT contains X, Y, 0, NAN as values. I am expecting only 2 values, x and y. Why am I getting 0 and NAN?

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_fc, ["FID", "Shape@WKT"]) as da_cursor:
    for row in da_cursor:
        geoms = row[1].replace(' ZM ','')
        print geoms
        pg_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (fid_p, geom) VALUES (%s, ST_GeometryFromText('%s', %s))" %(dataset_name, int(row[0]), geoms, int(coordinate_system)))
pg_connection.commit()
```

RESULT of print geoms:

MULTIPOLYGON ZM (((440185.43178632273 6350644.499023444 0 NAN, 440189.09859540447 6350575.940429694 0 NAN, .........

PYTHON ERROR:

InternalError: parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "...85.43178632273 6350644.499023444 0 NA" <-- parse error at position 60 within geometry

Comment: I think there might be some confusion between what is actually encoded in the shapefile, which is the `MULTIPOLYGON ZM`, and what you want, which is just `MULTIPOLYGON`.  You are receiving a python error because there are values for the Z and M coordinates in the shapefile geometry.  You need to either resave the shapefile before running this script, to strip out the ZM values, or specify a parameter on this function to only look at the 2D elements.

Comment: It's actually trivial to just copy a shapefile to PostgreSQL using ArcGIS 10.4 or higher (a dozen lines of Python, with extensive documentation).

Comment: please share Vince

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last two values are Z and M values for each vertex. Looks like your dataset is Z/M enabled, but the features you're importing don't have values set, thus you see 0/NaN.

If you copy the features into a non ZM-enabled feature class, you won't have to worry about the ZM replace or parsing the 0/NaNs in the WKT string.